# Installing and upgrading help Data directory (/var/www/moodledata) cannot be created by the installer

Tags: apache, docker, moodle

I'm trying to deploy Moodle into Docker.

Here is the steps I followed:

First, create a new network for the application and the database:

```
$ docker network create moodle
```

Then, start a new database process in an isolated container:

```
$ docker run --name mysql --network moodle -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql
```

Finally, you can run this moodle image and link it to your mysql container:

```
$ docker run --name my-moodle --network moodle --link mysql:database -p 8080:80 -d aesr/moodle
```

Access it via `http://localhost:8080` or `http://host-ip:8080` in a browser.

But while installing moodle I'm getting this error:

> Data directory (/var/www/moodledata) cannot be created by the installer.

Maybe because of Apache doesn't have the proper permission. I'm running Docker on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

My solutions worked on Centos 7.

Just move out the moodledata to somewhere else, like

`mkdir /moodledata`

`chown -R apache:apache /moodledata`

Because it calls the folder `/var` can be expose from internet and not accept to start the Installation